# Passing AttributeSet to childs of custom ViewPager via PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view, android-pageradapter, android-attributes

My problem - child of ViewPager views can't get attributes from AttributeSet.
I make custom ViewGroup including ViewPager:

```
public class CustomCalendarView extends FrameLayout {
...

public CustomCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
    init(context, attr);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    ...
    _viewPager = new ViewPager(context, attributeSet);
    _pagerAdapter = new MonthPagerAdapter(_minDate, _maxDate, attributeSet);
    ...
    addView(_viewPager);
    _viewPager.setAdapter(_pagerAdapter);
    ...
}
```

In adapter i save AttributeSet object and pass it into child of ViewPager view on creation step:

```
private class MonthPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private final Calendar _minDate;
    private final Calendar _maxDate;
    private final AttributeSet _attributeSet;

    public MonthPagerAdapter(Calendar min, Calendar max, AttributeSet attr){
        _minDate = min;
        _maxDate = max;
        _attributeSet = attr;
    }

    @Override public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        MonthView v = new MonthView(getContext(), _attributeSet);
        ...
        container.addView(v);
        return v;
    }
    ...
}
```

Example of attributes (i was try set name for declare-styleable as "CustomCalendarView" - nothing changes)

```
<declare-styleable name="MonthView">
    <attr name="day_text_size" format="dimension"/>
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

Example of usage custom view in xml:

```
    <my_app_package.views.CustomCalendarView
        xmlns:calendar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        calendar:day_text_size="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"/>
```

In child view i try to get that attributes:

```
...
if (attr != null) {
   TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attr, R.styleable.MonthView, defStyle, 0);
   if (a != null) {
       _dayTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.MonthView_day_text_size, _dayTextSize);
       ...
   }
}
```

So, TypedArray a not null, but on get dimention returns passed default value.
If i set MonthView directly in xml and will set attributes - its works, but not in a PagerAdapter.
How can I fix it and make the view visible attributes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand AttributeSet correctly, you can only access the attributes in the constructor, so trying to save a copy and pass them down won't work.  You need to use a TypedArray in the constructor and parse out all the data - then pass the data down to your other classes.